# SwinxyZoom: Customize Lens Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the lens and zoomed area a rectangle instead of a square (shown in image).  Any ideas on how to make this happen?  If I switch the mode to lens I am able to set the width, and height of the lens, but not when I do 'dock'.

```
$('a.swinxydock').swinxyzoom({mode:'dock', size: '100%', dock: { position: 'right'} });
```

[image]